# Alfresco Rest api get document shared link

Tags: java, rest, sdk, alfresco, alfresco-share

I need to share and unshare the content in alfresco using Rest API,

I read the [sharedLinks documentation](https://api-explorer.alfresco.com/api-explorer/#/shared-links/createSharedLink) but I don't know how to retrieve the document url I want to share.
This endpoint return an object with this properties :

```
{
  "entry": {
    "id": "string",
    "expiresAt": "2022-03-23T18:16:00.603Z",
    "nodeId": "string",
    "name": "string",
    "title": "string",
    "description": "string",
    "modifiedAt": "2022-03-23T18:16:00.603Z",
    "modifiedByUser": {
      "displayName": "string",
      "id": "string"
    },
    "sharedByUser": {
      "displayName": "string",
      "id": "string"
    },
    "content": {
      "mimeType": "string",
      "mimeTypeName": "string",
      "sizeInBytes": 0,
      "encoding": "string"
    },
    "allowableOperations": [
      "string"
    ],
    "allowableOperationsOnTarget": [
      "string"
    ],
    "isFavorite": true,
    "properties": {},
    "aspectNames": [
      "string"
    ],
    "path": {
      "elements": [
        {
          "id": "string",
          "name": "string",
          "nodeType": "string",
          "aspectNames": [
            "string"
          ]
        }
      ],
      "name": "string",
      "isComplete": true
    }
  }
}
```

How can i retrieve the path from the response?

Is there another way to get the effective complete shared link for a document ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The response returns you an ID of the share link.

Example:  `"id": "riqJ3xV3M4RNxJm6Haa7-w"`

Use this ID to access the share link :
https://your.alfresco.domaine/share/s/riqJ3xV3M4RNxJm6Haa7-w

You can also use this web service : [emailSharedLink](https://api-explorer.alfresco.com/api-explorer/#/shared-links/emailSharedLink) to send an email with the link to the shared document.

Comment: Thank you 3omar. This should be added to the rest api documentation. I didn't see any resource explaining how to use the generated shared link